# Test cases using mockito

Tags: junit, mockito, powermock

I have below method of a class.

```
public Response getProb(long Id) throws ResourceException
{
    final Response response = new Response();
    JSONObject headerObject = new JSONObject();
    String message = null;
    int status = 0;
    try
    {
        JSONObject getProb = new JSONObject();      
        getProb.put("id", Id);
        if (commonDao.validateIdCheck(getProb))
        {           
            headerObject.put(CommonConstants.LASTMOD_DATE, commonDao.lastModDate(Id));              
            response.setResource(headerObject);
            message="Retuned Successfully";
        }
        response.setStatus(message, status);
    }
    catch (JSONException exception)
    {
        throw new ResourceException(CommonErrorConstants.JSON_EXCEPTION, exception);
    }
    catch (ResourceException exception)
    {
        throw exception;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        throw new ResourceException(CommonErrorConstants.GENERAL_EXCEPTION, exception);
    }
    return response;
}
```

what will be the junit test cases using mockito which will give 100% code coverage.

Answer (score 0):

These are the cases you can test and achieve 100% coverage:

- validateIdCheck returns true
- validateIdCheck returns false
- your try block throws JSONException
- your try block throws ResourceException
- your try block throws Exception
- a success case where you return a response

Comment: Worth mentioning that is you practice TDD, you don't have to answer this question, as you write the test for the behavior before writing anything in the production code.